# При добавлении Angular Material DatePicker появляется второй input

Tags: angular2, datepicker, angular-material

Добавляю в проект Angular DatePicker, по непонятной причине добавляется дополнительное поле из-за чего искажается отображение элемента.

[image: Внешний вид поля:] 
Html стандартный из примера:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input class="input" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Файл app.modulers.ts содержит следующие модули:

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    PreloaderLazyModule,
    ToastModule.forRoot(),
    Ng2CompleterModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    TextMaskModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  providers: [
    DatePipe,
    Preloader
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

В чистом проекте все работает отлично, не могу разобраться с чем может быть связана проблема.

Comment: создай пример на stackblitz, чтоб можно было воспроизвести проблему

Comment: Вопрос решен, параллельно в style.scss были подключены стили materialize, из-за которых происходило дублирование элементов. Оставлю это здесь, возможно кому-то поможет.